# how to assign onclick events to dynamically-created buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a function that creates dynamic buttons and assigns them unique `id` and text values. They're created and rendered just fine on the UI, but I'd like to be able to assign them separate `onclick` event listeners.  The following is the logic in question:

```js
function createLinkButtons(){
      for(var i = 0; i < currentOrder.links.length; i++){
        currentLink = currentOrder.links[i]
        var currentHTML = linksButtonsDiv.innerHTML;
        linksButtonsDiv.innerHTML = currentHTML + 
        `
        <button type="button" id="${currentLink.rel}">${currentLink.rel}</button>
        `
        
        var button = new Object();

        button = document.getElementById(currentLink.rel) //<-- gets overwritten by the next loop iteration
        
        var rel = currentLink.rel;

        //onclick function should receive param argument to know how to proceed accordingly
        button.onclick = function(rel){
          console.log("it workded"); 
        }

      }
    }
```

Interestingly, I am able to set the `onclick` event to the LAST button that gets created.  This is because the last button that gets created "keeps" the `onclick` reference.  How can I keep all of the previous references to the button alive in memory so that they also react when I click on them?

I've seen [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987490/assign-event-handlers-to-dynamically-created-buttons) in which the dynamically-created buttons are assiged an `onclick` event dynamically, but the function is just a signature and does not accept a param argument.  I need to include a param argument when invoking the onclick event. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: At first, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177040/how-to-assign-onclick-events-to-dynamically-created-buttons-using-javascript , then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have an issue with your code, because once you create a button, inject it in the DOM and attach an event, then the next iteration of your loop is simply removing it and creating a new instance of the button (with same id).

To fix it, you should not modifying the whole HTML but rather append child dynamically:
Initial code:

```js
linksButtonsDiv.innerHTML = currentHTML + 
`<button type="button" id="${currentLink.rel}">${currentLink.rel}</button>`
```

New Code:

```js
let button= document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute('id', currentLink.rel);
button.innerHTML = currentLink.rel;
linksButtonsDiv.parentNode.appendChild(button);
function onClick() {
   console.log("it workded");
}
button.addEventListener("click", onClick, false);
```

PS: It's a detail but this is not the most efficient way to do, it's better to push all your buttons at once in the DOM and then attach events.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `let` instead of `var`

```
for(let i = 0; i < currentOrder.links.length; i++){
    ...
```

`var` is function scoped

`let` is block scoped

When using `var` in this instance, all the `JQuery` inside the loop reads the last defined value for your `i` variable, which is `currentOrder.links.length - 1` -- that's why the last button works

Comment: Actually your answer is not valid, the issue is not with var or let, both works perfectly